# Javascript difference between "File" and "new File" constructors?

Tags: javascript, file

What's the difference between JS's "File" and "new File" constructors for a new file?

I.e., what's the difference between:

```
var f = File("C:/myfile.txt");
```

and

```
var f = new File("C:/myfile.txt");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the first way actually work?

Comment: There is a difference in how a function works with or without `new` but since `File` isn't part of the JS language (it must be an object provided by your host environment or a library) then whether or not that has a practical difference depends on the implementation of it. Where are you getting this File object from?

Comment: @David Dorward, the File object is actually part of the javascript/DOM in a browser, but it cannot be instantiated by a script (due to security concerns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `File` object in [ECMAScript-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262-arch.htm).

Maybe you mean the `File` object of ExtendedScript (Adobe CS)?

```
File ([path]); //can return a Folder object
new File ([path]); //always returns a File object
```

Source: [JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS5](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign/scripting/pdfs/JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS5.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! I am indeed using Adobe's ES; didn't know that wasn't standard JS (Is it in HTML5 as Shadow says?). However, your source link appears broken to me..

Comment: @Sella: yeah, link seems to be broken now. It wasn't at the time checking (even Google still lists it ^^). Here's [another one](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS5.pdf).
And for your side question: yes there is a `File` object in HTML5, but afaik it is bound to `<input type="file" />` objects and non-scriptable.